# I'm Italian and I'll have one month vacations in Australia. What documents do I need to apply to the eVisitor Subclass 651?

Tags: visas, australia, italian-citizens

I'm planning to stay in Australia for one month from December 4 to January 7. I've seen that I can apply online for the eVisitor 651, which is free, but before applying it doesn't say anything about any other documents besides passport.

Do I need anything else in order to apply for this type of visa?

Answer (score 3):

The only document you need is your passport. The form also asks things like your address (residential and email) and whether you have a criminal record, but no documents are required (at least if you don't have one).